# Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference for log4net

Tags: msbuild, log4net, csproj, log4net-configuration, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have updated log4net version from 2.0.5 to 2.0.12 in a project. Package.config and .csproj file content changed accordingly. But, msbuild is giving
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "log4net". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

It is causing log4net error. Considered "..\packages\log4net.2.0.12\lib\net45\log4net.dll", but it didn't exist.

How to resolve this error? My csproj file contains hintpath of parent package folder
..\packages\log4net.2.0.12\lib\net45\log4net.dll

Comment: did you execute a nuget restore before the build?

Comment: yes @MartinUllrich

Comment: got the same error on azure pipeline